# Import node_module plugin css to next js project

Tags: css, reactjs, import, node-modules, next.js

Here, I am trying to import plugin and it's css like this

```
import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';
import 'react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';
```

In this case css won't load.

When i do like this:

```
import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';
import stylesheet from 'react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';

<div>        
<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stylesheet }} />
</div>
```

Now css works but still css can't load image.

Can you guys please help me on this: why css is not being loaded in direct import??

Answer (score 0):

Try just -

```
import './main.css';
```

You can also use the required module -

```
require('./main.css');
const style = require('react');
```

Comment: Here, I am trying to import css of node_modules not from static folder css.

Comment: Ok, if you're trying to import it from node_modules try import from your root folder and replace the node_modules/ with a tilde ~ this way:   @import '~react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css';